# What legal relief is available when a neighbour uses my address as his own for communication without written consent from me?

Tags: india, tort

A property, say plot no.31, was sub-divided into two parts. After subdivision the plot number on record for the newly created subdivision was, say, 31-A; the original plot number remained 31.

The division was challenged, and the challenge dismissed at all levels after the first initial success. Many years later, after the challenger passed away and that sub-division was inherited by the challenger's heirs, it was discovered that even after dismissal the challenger continued to use the postal address of the challenged sub-division. This continued for years even when the heirs too knew from record that the address was 31-A instead of 31. When asked the postal department stated the address being next door, all mail was delivered assuming the misstated address  to be simple oversight by the sender/s. Even assuming defence by 31-A claim the misrepresentation was by oversight, it comes across as far-fetched for such oversight to continue for whole decades.

What legal relief is available when a neighbour uses my address as his own for communication without written consent from me? Is the the postal department also culpable?

EDIT: To follow up with @eis' answer that tort demands establishing damage here is my concern. Documents which establish proof of address s.a. Utility Bills - telephone, energy, water service lose clarity. If so inclined, one may call this behaviour causing loss of value to the property simply because it amounts to squatting - if only on paper.

EDIT 2: Pursuant to the comment by R.M below, an additional question that comes to mind is as follows -

- Could such use of my address as an alias for their own address serve to establish 'proof of residence'? For instance, some days ago I encountered a pizza delivery boy waiting outside my premises. Upon enquiry he intimated the pizza was to be delivered to them but the address given by them was mine.

Comment: Does this person get so much mail you need legal relief?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-: Their mail are delivered to their residence but the address on their communication/s is mine.

Comment: If their mail gets delivered to their address and yours to yours, does the current solution cause anyone any actual harm (except for the "insult" of them using your address)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. It seems you are getting your correct mail and they are getting their correct mail. Why are you so concerned by this seemingly irrelevant detail?

Comment: How is everyone getting all of their mail correctly if the same address is being used?  I mean, I get that the mail-carrier might be able to make judgements based on the residents' names if they've learned who lives where (is that the case?), but what about mail addressed more generically, e.g. addressed to "_Resident_"?

Comment: My best guess is that OP is not using that address for mail yet and is perhaps looking to start using it but doesn't want all their mail to go to the neighbors (or perhaps has no plans to use this as a mailing address)...  OP has said the neighbors get their mail correctly, but has not confirmed receiving their own mail at that address as far as I can tell.

Comment: @ttbek The OP says this has been going on for decades. And in comments below the answers they say both parties are getting their mail correctly.

Comment: So nothing bad is actually happening, it's just confusing and/or annoying you that they're using your address?

Comment: I moved into a house where the prior resident had very poor credit. I found out that she was still using the address periodically, despite my writing "no longer at this address" on various creditors letters. One day she even had the cheek to turn up to ask for any post that had been left. After that I started writing "Deceased" on the letters and they stopped immediately.

Comment: For clarity, perhaps add what the address should be for each party.   Such as 31 is your address, 32 is your neighbor's actual address, 31-A is the address being used by your neighbor for correspondence and that your postal service effectively recognizes as an alias for 32.  Is this a correct summary of the situation, or is there something else.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson: Yes. 31A is what they *should* write. They write 31 - which is mine. The post office delivers their mail to their address 31A even though what is written on the mail is 31. This is because it is right next-door on the beat! I've described the situation in the body of this issue already.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  For additional information, what harm is being inflicted upon you?

Comment: @MichaelRichardson: I've edited the description with the potential harm; loss of value to the property as their behaviour potentially establishes *them* as squatters.

Comment: Whether the law recognizes them as squatters would seem to be a different question.  And how do you know that they are omitting the letter "A" from their address if their mail is being delivered to them?  And what does the division being challenged have to do with it?

Comment: @MichaelHall: A messenger came to my property to deliver a consignment with my address and their name. I did a bit of digging thereafter.

Comment: @Nat: Their property is next-door on the postman's beat; she/he simply relies upon the name assuming the address to be a typo/oversight.

Comment: @MichaelHall: The division being challenged, and their subsequent loss - in my mind - provides a motive for them to establish themselves as squatters in this fashion. I may be paranoid, or I may be right ...

Comment: There's a lot more than just mail at stake if you are asserting the potential for squatting.  For instance, if a subdivision was challenged and rejected wouldn't that make the original owner of 31 also the owner of 31A?  If that is true, I'm presuming that 31A does NOT have a lease agreement with 31?  Who is listed on the titles, and paying the property tax on each property?  I realize my questions are way out of scope for the basic question you asked, but this seems like a real mess...

Comment: @MichaelHall: The division was challenged, and the challenge - asking the division be deleted - was initially upheld; it was then rejected in appeal. The taxes due are paid by the residents of each part separately - as far as I know. p.s. The squatting (in addition to other squatty tactics which I realised after learning about the squatting) make it a mess.

Comment: OK, I will punt on any further questions.  In the US a "division" would create two individual properties for tax purposes so the fact that they are taxed as distinctly separate units would seem to indicate some recognition of a "division".  Otherwise I have no context for what that word actually means in this situation...

Comment: @Everyone, how do you know what address is being written on mail addressed to him, that arrives in his mailbox? Did you look in his mailbox? (I hope not) Did the postman tell you this? (With what right?) If one single delivery arrived to you by mistake, why are you assuming that all other deliveries are mislabeled?

Comment: @Everyone Your question is talking about mail delivery, but it sounds like you're actually concerned about the use of the incorrectly addressed mail as future evidence in a property claim/official action. (e.g. the owners committing fraud by claiming that the mail proves they're the rightful owners of the property.) -- You're likely to get better answers if you asked directly about those hypothetical future actions. (e.g. "Is it possible to use such incorrectly addressed mail to start fraudulent legal actions?" and/or "What can I do now to protect myself from such potential future actions?")

Comment: @R.M. You're right, that is a much more relevant question to ask. Let me see if such editing will be acceptable.

Comment: Can you say what, if any, damage anyone has suffered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the fact that utility bills can be used to prove title to the property is in itself a cause for worry, and can also constitute a cause of action by itself. This is due to the mere fact that these documents, can in fact, constitute proof of address, for example, for [GST registration](https://cleartax.in/s/gst-registration-documents-checklist) of the individual.

Further, you can refer to the following court cases which have treated utility bills as proof of title on a balance of probabilities.

1. [Nileshkumar Hiralal Modi v/s Hitesh Kaushi Kumar Modi](https://www.lawyerservices.in/Nileshkumar-Hiralal-Modi-Versus-Hitesh-Kaushi-Kumar-Modi-2012-07-17) at paragraphs 10 and 15.
2. [Rabari Nagjibhai Maneklal vs Nilamben Upendrabhai Shah](https://indiankanoon.org/doc/79916882/) at paragraph 56

Since you are the owner of property with presumably a perfect title, you are entitled to file a suit for **mandatory injunction** which will prevent the neighbour from using your address, there being "*no standard to ascertain the actual damage caused*". This relief is provided under [Section 38 of the Specific Relief Act, 1963](https://www.indiacode.nic.in/show-data?actid=AC_CEN_3_20_00009_196347_1517807320084&sectionId=30253&sectionno=38&orderno=42).

You must also bear in mind that, if the neighbour also claims title, you may have to contest the title to the suit property since this remedy will not then be available to you, and instead you will have to claim for declaratory relief first as per the guidelines by the Supreme Court of India in paragraph 13 of [Anathula Sudhakar vs P. Buchi Reddy (Dead) By Lrs & Ors](https://indiankanoon.org/doc/540361/)

Comment: This comes across as just the guidelines I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

Mark the mail delivered as "addressee unknown, return to sender" and give it to the postal delivery person next time around. If the mail stops getting through, the neighbor will update their address.

Comment: His mail aren't coming to me; they are being delivered at his address next door - but the address on the mail is mine.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question, at all..... And shouldn't answers refrain from giving legal advice? This answer seems nothing more than instruction on how to proceed; there is not even informational justification.

Comment: @Everyone Then I clearly misunderstood the situation. The clarifying comments in the question weren't there when I first read it and the title question and body seem to be actually asking different things.

Comment: @Krow Some legal questions have answers that are more practical than embedded in case law and regulations. The further you get from a courtroom, the more likely it is that this will be the case.

Comment: @ohwilleke: I'm sorry I wasn't clear; but now I'm confused. How is it the body, and title appear to ask different things?

Comment: @Everyone In the title it sound like the third-party is gratuitously having mail meant for them sent to your mailbox. But it appears that the actual question is the converse of that, with mail meant for you going to a neighbor's box.

Comment: The mail meant for them *is* going to *them*. The problem is - as Michael Richardson noted in his comments above - my address is being used as an alias and without my consent.

Answer (score 12):

Based on the description, there is no legal relief available.

To quote:

> a tort is breach of a non-contractual duty which has caused damage to
> the plaintiff giving rise to a civil cause of action and for which
> remedy is available.

To establish a tort, you need to establish that damage has occurred. Since mail is simply being delivered to the correct location despite the address, and you don't claim any harm having occurred, it does not sound like you have suffered any damage, hence no legal relief is available.

---

You added:

> Documents which establish proof of address s.a. Utility Bills - telephone, energy, water service lose clarity. If so inclined, one may call this behaviour causing loss of value to the property simply because it amounts to squatting - if only on paper.

But you need to establish damage having happened. In general you would need to have receipts proving the amount of money you have lost. You don't have a bill to pay for losing clarity, hence you can't prove that you've suffered any damage.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've updated the description to clarify what I believe is the damage done.

Comment: @Everyone I updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 5):

### None

Unless the neighbour was a company (which, since they died, they can’t be), or they are giving out false information (like the address) with the intention of committing a crime like fraud.

You could, perhaps, have sought an injunction for them to stop but it seems unlikely the court would grant it since it doesn’t appear to have caused you or anyone else any harm. In any event, any remedy you might have had ended with the person’s death.

Comment: That person's heirs have kept up with the same; their communication address is mine, but they live in the next building over.

Comment: How sure are you that this answer applies in *India*? They are derived from the UK, but with local adjustments.